# Receiving updated object from Detail fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a StudentList fragment, which has a List; the Student class implements Parcelable; clicking an item in the StudentList fragment invokes the StudentFragment (using Student.newInstance(selectedStudent)).

The user is allowed to update the selectedStudent object in the Student fragment. I need to receive these updates back in the StudentList fragment after the user clicks "Save" in the StudentFragment.

How should I achieve this?

(I assume its a bad idea to use a Singleton to hold the selectedStudent because the state may be lost on device rotation or when the app goes into the background)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check this article on the android doc on `How to communicate between fragments` : http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

It is very good explained. I implemented this on my own projet and it works perfectly fine. If you have any question on that, do not hesitate !

Comment: The part I'm not clear about is what to do after the user clicks Save. Do I send the Updated object back to the parent activity using a call back, and then send it via a message to the List Fragment? Another option is to use setTargetFragment() from the List Fragment, and then directly sending the updated object back using getTargetFragment.onActivityResult(). Are there any drawbacks to this approach?

Comment: You are right. You send the updated object back to the parent activity using a call back, and then send it via a message to the List Fragment. It is how I did.

Comment: Thanks! One last question, I assume the above will work only for dual-mode layout, when both Fragments are visible. But if the app is in single-mode/pane layout (portrait mode on a phone), will the parent Activity need to bundle the object into an argument before passing it to the ListFragment, and then ListFragment should retrieve it from getArguments in onCreate? That's what the Android link you provided seems to be doing.

Comment: No, it work even if the second fragment is not visible. Your ListFragment just need to be instanciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should make a `Students` database using `SQLite`. And update the `tables` when the user changes data. The reflect it in the list from `database`

Comment: This amounts to serializing and deserializing the object. As the data is transient (and ultimately uploaded to the cloud) I its better to implement Parcelable and pass the Object around in a bundle/intent instead of using SQLite.